# C++ code plus C# GUI

Tags: opencv, dll, service, c++-cli, tesseract

I am making program which is using tesseract, opencv, SDL, word automation and maybe other libraries in future, written on C++. What is the best GUI I can make(MFC,C++/CLI,ATL,WTL,C#) - fastest for development? Is tesseract, opencv, SDL libraries written on unmnaged or managed C++? Is there a way unmanaged library written on C++ to be used in C++/CLR or C#? Also I heared about something like "Services". Do they allow combination of languages and GUI development and which is better(or faster for developing) -> dll or services?

Comment: You probably can use C# GUI with C++ code, but what for? QT is a very good GUI for C++

Comment: Managed or unmanaged C++, and does it have tools for office automation??

Comment: QT is standalone and doesn't depend on .NET, so, it's unmanaged C++. I believe there _may be_ some tools like this, but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really broad, thus I will focus on some important points:

1. C and C++ libraries can be used in C++/CLI
2. Assemblies written in C# can easily access managed code (`ref class`es or `value class`es) in assemblies written in C++/CLI
3. There are basically 2 GUI Frameworks available in .NET: WPF and Windows Forms. It is even possible to use Windows Forms directly from C++/CLI, **but: Don't do it!** Instead:

   - Write wrapper code for the native libraries in C++/CLI
   - Choose a GUI framework and implement your GUI in C#
   - use the native libraries via your C++/CLI-Wrappers

**Edit** - An example for a very simple wrapper:

```
// native includes
#include <Windows.h>
#include <lmcons.h>

namespace My 
{
    // a managed class which is public and can be used by other assemblies
    public ref class Wrapper
    {
    public:
        // a function with a managed return type 
        static System::String^ CallNativeFunction()
        {
            // call native function
            DWORD length = UNLEN;
            wchar_t userName[UNLEN];
            GetUserName(userName, &length);

            // convert result of native function to managed System::String
            System::String^ result = gcnew System::String(userName, 0, length);

            return result;
        }
    };
} // namespace

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // usage of the wrapper class
    System::Console::WriteLine(My::Wrapper::CallNativeFunction());
    return 0;
}
```

In your C# project you could add a reference to the C++/CLI project and then simply call `My.Wrapper.CallNativeFunction()`.

Comment: I know about C++/CLI and I have tried it, but found out there is significant difference between managed and unmanaged C++ sintax, so do this mean I can use tesseract 3.02, opencv 2.4.11 , SDL 2.0 in C++/CLI which **is not recommended**, becouse I tried and there were errors in a lot of header files? What do you mean to write wrapper - for tesseract? If so - there are written wrappers for version 3.02 for C# and the price is big for me. I think tesseract 3.02 for visual studio is unmanaged and it is needed to reference .lib files together with .dll. I dont want whole tesseract functionality.

Comment: I've added an example. I'm not familiar with tesseract or SDL, but I'v already used OpenCV with C++/CLI. Make sure to compile your project with "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)" not "/clr:pure" or "clr:pure". Then you can mix both kind of syntax.

Comment: The compilation will run successful with both sintaxs, BUT THE DESIGNER CRASHES and that is slowing my work. I have read a lot of things befor asking my question, that is why it is so vague. Acctualy I am seraching of best way with less code - something like QT like ForceBru mentioned, becouse it is all in unmanaged C++ and no wrappers or unmanaged C++ to C# DLL additional descriptions are needed, but the bad thig is gnuWin32 compiler and that QT need compilation of the libraries code, and less support is avilable. I will approve your answer for right according to the title of the thread.

Comment: The designer problem is one of the reasons why I wrote the "don't do it" sentence.